# .htaccess Let sibling folder to be accessible from current folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a directory structure like this.

```
www/
---A/
   ---.htaccess
---B/
   ---index.php
   ---.htaccess
---C/
```

Folder A is accesible using `a.com`, but folder B doesn't has domain yet.
How can I access B folder from `url` like `a.com/B/index.php` by manipulating `.htaccess`?

And also, which `.htaccess` I need to modify?

Or do I need to modify configuration in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since sub-directory `B/` is not inside `A/` therefore you cannot access it from `A.com` without server side changes.

However, looks like you have control over Apache server config. You can declare an `Alias` inside your `<VirtualHost>` section of `A.com` like this:

```
Alias "/B" "/full/path/www/B"

<Directory /full/path/www/B>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Replace `/full/path/www/B` with your actual full path.

Now you can access `B/` with `http://A.com/B/`. If you place a `.htaccess` inside `B/` directory, it will control URIs starting with `/B/` only.

Comment: thank you, i will try this and will inform you as well as marking this question as answered.